# Google Composer failing to install private Artifacts package

Tags: python, google-cloud-platform, airflow, google-cloud-build, google-artifact-registry

I'm trying to install a python package from Google Artifacts to our Google Composer environment.

I followed the steps here:

https://towardsdatascience.com/if-you-are-using-python-and-google-cloud-platform-this-will-simplify-life-for-you-part-2-bef56354fd4c

https://cloud.google.com/composer/docs/how-to/using/installing-python-dependencies#console

```
gcloud composer environments update test --update-pypi-package testpackage==0.34 --location europe-west2
```

I'm getting a very obscure error from the Cloud Build logs:

```
Step 7/11 : RUN bash installer.sh $COMPOSER_PYTHON_VERSION  fail
+ COMPOSER_PYTHON_VERSION=3
+ FAIL_ON_CONFLICT=fail
+ '[' 3 == 3 ']'
+ PYTHON=python3
+ echo 'Installing Python3 Requirements.'
Installing Python3 Requirements.
+ python3 -m pip install -r requirements.txt
Looking in indexes: https://pypi.org/simple, https://europe-west1-python.pkg.dev/gcp-project-name/repo-name/simple/
ERROR: Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement testpackage==0.34 (from -r requirements.txt (line 1)) (from versions: none)
ERROR: No matching distribution found for testpackage==0.34 (from -r requirements.txt (line 1))
The command '/bin/sh -c bash installer.sh $COMPOSER_PYTHON_VERSION  fail' returned a non-zero code: 1
ERROR
ERROR: build step 0 "gcr.io/cloud-builders/docker" failed: step exited with non-zero status: 1
```

You can see it's picking up the extra index (https://europe-west1-python.pkg.dev/gcp-project-name/repo-name/simple/) from the pip.conf file I created as per the steps, but looks like it's not even trying it? Because then I should get a different error.

If I test just the install locally on my machine it works using the same pip.conf setup. I checked all the logs in Cloud logging, there's literall nothing. All I see there is:

```
Critical error.
Failed to install pypi packages.
```

Is there somewhere I can look to get a more descriptive error perhaps?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 1):

Have you granted permissions to the Composer Service Agent service account? This is the service account GCP will use to create the resources for Cloud Composer in your project.

If this service account does not have permission to view and get artifacts from your repository, updating the environment will fail when you try to install an artifact from the repository into the Cloud Composer environment.

By default this has the `Cloud Composer API Service Agent` role which includes:

- `artifactregistry.repositories.create`
- `artifactregistry.repositories.delete`
- `artifactregistry.repositories.get`
- `artifactregistry.repositories.list`
- `artifactregistry.repositories.update`

Try granting this service account the `roles/artifactregistry.reader` role in your project.

The documentation for the Composer Service Account is [here](https://cloud.google.com/composer/docs/composer-2/access-control#composer-sa) and you can view what permissions the role that comes with it [here](https://cloud.google.com/composer/docs/composer-2/access-control#permissions-service-agent).

The roles and permissions for artifact registry are [here](https://cloud.google.com/artifact-registry/docs/access-control#roles).

Comment: This was insufficient to solve my problem.  I provided `artifactregistry.reader` to the composer service agent and it still provides the same error.  I am able to install the packages myself, so I'm pretty sure it's an access problem.

Answer (score 0):

I eventually figured out the real problem that I had (mentioned in the comment Daniel's answer). It was a problem because of (a) cross-project access needed, and (b) a *hidden* service account that Composer uses.

## Cross-project Artifact Registry Access

We needed to edit our *Config Connector* for IAM membership to the following:

```yaml
apiVersion: iam.cnrm.cloud.google.com/v1beta1
kind: IAMPolicyMember
metadata:
  name: composer-x-prj-dev-artifactregistry-reader
spec:
  member: serviceAccount:composer@my-project.iam.gserviceaccount.com
  role: roles/artifactregistry.reader
  resourceRef:
    kind: Project
    external: projects/other-project
```

I thought this would solve it because this is the service account that I associated with Cloud Composer.

## Hidden Service Account

However, when Cloud Composer is *building itself*, it does not do this via the service account that you associate with it. Instead, it uses the build agent's service account, and *you have no choice but to use this build agent service account*.

So we needed to give that build agent further access. So I had to fix the helm chart above with the proper service account:

```yaml
apiVersion: iam.cnrm.cloud.google.com/v1beta1
kind: IAMPolicyMember
metadata:
  name: composer-x-prj-dev-artifactregistry-reader
spec:
  member: serviceAccount:<my-project-NUMBER>@cloudbuild.gserviceaccount.com
  role: roles/artifactregistry.reader
  resourceRef:
    kind: Project
    external: projects/other-project
```

This is identical to the earlier one except for the member listed. Note that *you will not find that service account listed anywhere in your IAM console or `gcloud` CLI*.  This is a hidden account that always exists for any project in GCP, and the account is always `<your_project_NUMBER>@cloudbuild.gserviceaccount.com`.